# transpile __dirname as a value

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I want to get the directory of the source file, so I want to use `__dirname` in my .ts file as a value, not a variable.

in other words, I want this code to output the same value whatever the location of the output.

/src/index.ts

```
console.log(__dirname); // -> /src
```

when transpiling this file via `tsc` into a different location, it should log the new location.
but I want to log the same value each time

/dist/index.js

```
console.log(__dirname); // -> /dist
```

what I want is that when I open `dist/index.js` to see `cosole.log("/src")` instead of `console.log(__dirname)`

**why I do that?**

because sometimes you don't want to respect tsconfig.json, and output to a different path.

for instance using `ts-node src/index.ts`  acts as if it outputs the compiled file into the same directory of the spurce file, so __dirname here gives the same path as the source file

another example using `jest` you need to transpile .ts files on the fly rather than compiling it into the dist folder then running the test.

you then need to refer to a path relatively to a fixe
d point, whatever the output file lives.